# Webpack minify js and compile scss in multiple subdirectories

Tags: javascript, webpack, composer-php

I am trying to create a build system using webpack for a better development workflow with a PHP project.
The source repos are all cloned in a `/vendor/` directory, but to be accessible to PHP, they need to land in a `/source/` directory. My plan is to work in the `vendor` dir and have webpack automatically copy all files over when they are changed.

This is working out pretty well with the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: [],                    // empty so far, since only the CopyPlugin does something atm
  output: { path: __dirname },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "**/*",
          to: ".",
          context: "vendor/myVendor/",
          transformPath(targetPath, absolutePath) {
            return "source/modules/myVendor/" + targetPath;
          },
          globOptions: {
            ignore: ["**/resources/**/*"],
          },
        },
      ],
    })
  ],
};
```

As you can see, this copies all files in a module, which are not in a resources folder. That's what this question is about.

The folder structure is like so:

```
  /vendor
    /myvendor
      /mymodule1        <- just one of many modules - this should work for all of them
        composer.json
        /Application
          /Controller
            TestController.php
        /resources
          /js/minifyme.js          <- this should be processed...
          /css/coolcss.sass        <- ...also this one...
        /out
          /src
            /js/minifyme.min.js    <- ...and copied here
            /css/coolcss.css       <- ...or here, respectively
```

My plan is to have Javascript and CSS compiled/transpiled and put in a relative folder `/out/src/`, from where they are then copied to the `/source` folder by the CopyPlugin.

What is the best way to do this?